# Web API CurrentMessageContext Null

Tags: nservicebus

I have the following method in a api controller

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public Task<CommandResponse> Send(CommandBase command)
{
    var result = new TaskCompletionSource<CommandResponse>();

    this.Bus.Send(command).Register<int>(response =>
         {
          this.Bus.CurrentMessageContext is here null <-------
          result.TrySetResult(commandResponse);
         });
    return result.Task;
 }
```

Any idea why the CurrentMessageContext is here null. I'm following the Request/Response example. The only difference here is the async pattern using Task.

Thanks,
Marinko

Comment: what is it you're trying to access on the message context?

Comment: the headers set before the response was sent

Comment: What happens if you do not use Task?

Answer (score 2):

The callback is being fired in another thread and because `Bus.CurrentMessageContext` uses `ThreadStatic` attribute the value is null if accessed from a different thread.

Comment: I was having this sort of problems and I got to the same conclusion as you. Do you have any suggestion to fix this? I can only think of removing all the async stuff or wait for NSB 6.

Answer (score 0):

As in AsyncPagesMVC3 sample, you have to explicitly call the Install function, please see the last line at the Application_Start() method from Global.asax.cs:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // NServiceBus configuration
        Configure.WithWeb()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .ForMvc()
            .JsonSerializer()
            .Log4Net()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(false)
                .PurgeOnStartup(true)
            .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
    }
```

Comment: the callback is executed as expected. The Install method doesn't help. I would like to access the this.Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers inside of the callback. I think the issue is related to the threads. The worker thread is not the same like the callback thread, but I'm not sure.